# How to prevent soft bodies from moving and only deform?

Tags: edit-mode, physics, soft-body

I'm trying to vibrate a uv-sphere using soft body dynamics. But along with compressions, the sphere also drifts away as shown in the animation.

Please provide a solution to prevent its translation.
[image]

Comment: First thing that comes to mind it to place a (possibly invisible) Collision object behind it to block it. Or check the box next to Goal in the Soft Body settings in the Physics Properties tab.